# Selfie camera crash in camera plugin in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, camera

Whenever i try to open front camera from `camera` plugin in my project app crashes on Pixel 3XL, however app works fine on back camera.

plugin version : `camera: ^0.5.8+1`

My camera class.

```
class CameraState extends State<Camera> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraController controller;
  List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  @override initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCameras();
  }

  void getCameras() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    cameras.forEach((camera) {
      if (camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front) {
        onNewCameraSelected(camera);
      }
    });
  }

  /// Returns a suitable camera icon for [direction].
  IconData getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return Icons.camera_rear;
      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return Icons.camera_front;
      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;
    }
    throw ArgumentError('Unknown lens direction');
  }

  /// Display the preview from the camera (or a message if the preview is not available).
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return new Center(
        child: new Text(
          allTranslations.text('camera_no'),
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontFamily: fontMontserrat,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
      return Transform.scale(
        scale: controller.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
        child: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: CameraPreview(controller),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  void onNewCameraSelected(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.medium, enableAudio: false);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    });

    try {
      ///
      /// APP CRASHES HERE.
      /// 
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void onTakePictureButtonPressed() {
    takePicture().then((String filePath) {
      if (filePath != null) {
       // Navigate to other screen.
      }
    });
  }

  Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return null;
    }
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0,
          child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
        ),
        Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(allTranslations.text('licensescan_back'),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color:  Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontFamily: fontSourceSansPro,
                        fontStyle:  FontStyle.normal,
                        fontSize: 18.0
                    )
                ),
                Container(height: 10),
                Padding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  child: new Text(allTranslations.text('licensescan_positionback'),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color:  Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontFamily: fontSourceSansPro,
                          fontStyle:  FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 13.0
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: new Container()),
                new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: onTakePictureButtonPressed,
                    child: new Container(
                      width: 54, height: 54,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),
                          color: Colors.transparent
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: new Container(
                          width: 45, height: 45,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.5),
                              color: Colors.white
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ),
                new Container(height: 58)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Crash logs

```
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702): Process: com.craypay.app, PID: 23702
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at f.b.c.b.g.d(Unknown Source:5)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at f.b.c.b.g$b.onOpened(Unknown Source:7)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:143)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
08-31 10:24:07.816 E/AndroidRuntime(23702):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Also tried almost all solutions on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19595) but no luck.

Comment: Solution: use a different version of the library. As the github issue suggest it is simply broken, nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had crash with camera takepicture function.

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$DeviceOrientation.ordinal()'
> on a null object reference E/AndroidRuntime(18591):   at
> io.flutter.plugins.camera.DeviceOrientationManager.getMediaOrientation(DeviceOrientationManager.java:58)"

For  me helped adding
await controller.lockCaptureOrientation() after initialize().
Try this, maybe it will help you

```
   try {
          ///
          /// APP CRASHES HERE.
          /// 
          await controller.initialize();
          await controller.lockCaptureOrientation();

        }
```